# how to group object by property values using underscore

Tags: underscore.js

What's a good way to group object keys by their property values, for example:

```
var obj = { "user1": true, "user2": false, "user3": true };
```

into

```
{ true: ["user1", "user3"], false: ["user2"] }
```

I've tried something like this unsuccessfully

```
_.chain(obj).groupBy("type")
 .map(function(value, key) {
     type: key,
     username: value
 }).value()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go straight to [`reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) for this, something like:

```
var grouped = _(obj).reduce(function(m, k, v) {
    if(!m[k])
        m[k] = [ ];
    m[k].push(v);
    return m;
}, { });
```